# Возможно ли установить TWRP на HTC 10 Lifestyle 2PS6300?

Tags: flash, восстановление, android-adb

Я все делаю по инструкциях по интернету, скачиваю последнюю версию **TWRP** прошиваю раздел recovery пишет что все успешно, но если я перехожу в Recovery mode то он пишет "**This build is for development purposes only do not distribute outside of HTC without HTC's permission**" и кидает в bootloader. Возможно ли установить **TWRP** на данную модель **HTC 10 2PS6300**?